# Isomorphism between two general linear group.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

If $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, the general linear group of $V$, written $GL(V)$, is the set of all bijective linear transformations $V\to V$, together with functional composition as group operation.

My question: Let $V$ and $W$ be infinite dimensional vector spaces over a field $F$.  Is the following statement true?

> $GL(V)\cong GL(W)$ if and only if $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$.

Please provide references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with $dim(V)=dim(W)$, if both vector spaces are infinite dimensional?

Comment: @user408858 I mean the cardinalities of bases of $V$ and $W$ are the same.

Comment: I believe $ | \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} | = |\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}| $, but I'm not sure if this is a counterexample (are the linear transformations between these sets ?)

Comment: @DerekHolt, I think I'm missing something. I can't quite understand how your comment implies the answer to the question is yes. The direction "if the dimensions are the same, the general linear groups are the same" is easy, but the other direction is not straightforward as far as I can see! (It appears that [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/186573) answer addresses this question).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you very much.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Sorry I had misread the question. I will delete my comment for now.